# Error when install picamera on python 3.5.2 windows 10

Tags: python

I tried to install the picamera to my python 3.5 on windows 10 with pip 9.

Also,i looked online and know that i need to install pyyaml and i did. Its really strange, some suggestion is that the pip need to be the same location as setup.py? which is even more confusing. Anyway, below is what i did, hope it help.

Excuted command:

```
pip install --user picamera
```

Command Output:

```
Collecting picamera
  Using cached picamera-1.13.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: picamera
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for picamera: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for picamera: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\picamera\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfj3othpnpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib
  creating build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\array.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\bcm_host.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\camera.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\color.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\display.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\encoders.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\exc.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\frames.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\mmal.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\mmalobj.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\renderers.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\streams.py -> build\lib\picamera
  copying picamera\__init__.py -> build\lib\picamera
  running egg_info
  writing picamera.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing requirements to picamera.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing dependency_links to picamera.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to picamera.egg-info\top_level.txt
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

  reading manifest file 'picamera.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'debian'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs'
  writing manifest file 'picamera.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

  installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
  running install
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\picamera\setup.py", line 101, in run
      with io.open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as cpuinfo:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/cpuinfo'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\picamera\setup.py", line 145, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\picamera\setup.py", line 140, in main
      cmdclass             = {'install': CustomInstallCommand},
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 240, in run
      self.run_command('install')
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\picamera\setup.py", line 113, in run
      raise ValueError('Unable to open /proc/cpuinfo')
  ValueError: Unable to open /proc/cpuinfo

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for picamera
Failed to build picamera
Installing collected packages: picamera
  Running setup.py install for picamera: started
    Running setup.py install for picamera: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\picamera\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-x3ancwkq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\picamera\setup.py", line 101, in run
        with io.open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as cpuinfo:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/cpuinfo'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\picamera\setup.py", line 145, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\picamera\setup.py", line 140, in main
        cmdclass             = {'install': CustomInstallCommand},
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\picamera\setup.py", line 113, in run
        raise ValueError('Unable to open /proc/cpuinfo')
    ValueError: Unable to open /proc/cpuinfo

    ----------------------------------------

  Failed building wheel for picamera
Command "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\picamera\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-x3ancwkq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\picamera\
```

Error occured:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/cpuinfo'
```

Tried to install it with pycharm and still no luck

Comment: I am getting same issue in python2.7 as well

Comment: turn out that it work fine on linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/cpuinfo'

Cause the file only exists in the linux or unix-like System , not in the Windows system or the mac System.That's why you can't intall successfully.

Comment: This is clearly mention in fac http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/faq.html

Comment: So does this mean there is no way to install picamera library on Windows? Why are you able to install other python libraries but not picamera? I just want the errors in my IDE to go away about not being able to import picamera...

Comment: Seems like its only available for linux, currently having this same exact problem in 2021.

Comment: @vijayky88 You are wrong. The current docs, as well as the archived docs at https://web.archive.org/web/20180117115921/picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/faq.html contain no mention of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem when i was working with Kivy and python

> Got an error saying "No module named picamera found"

Solution which helped me get through that :

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Yes.! it helped me, might work for you.

Edit : I tried this on Python 3.7 (OS : Windows 10)

Comment: If you post a comment as answer and mangled it such successfully it looks like an answer.... then make the last mile and include the OS and python version you tried this on. Now your answer does not answer the essential issue of OP's question which is OS related.

Comment: Sir but I used this command on python 3.7 and on windows 10 
Its just I could not install picamera but it didnt give me problem when i followed this step

Comment: This does not solve nor help in anyway the problem address.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's old, might be useful to anyone who runs into the same problem.
Steps.

1. Open terminal (if you have a virtual env, activate it)
2. type "set READTHEDOCS=True"
3. pip install picamera
   OR
   4.pip install picamera[array]